# Is this code safe from SQL injections? (and why)

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-injection

Is this code safe from SQL injections? Why?

```
public void AddPlayer(string username)
    {
        var query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Player(Username, RegisterDate) VALUES(@Username, @RegisterDate)";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegisterDate", DateTime.Now);
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    public DateTime GetRegisterDate(string username)
    {
        var query = "SELECT RegisterDate FROM dbo.Player WHERE Username = @Username";
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
            command.Connection.Open();
            return (DateTime)command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** Could injection-safe equivalent code be written using a stored procedure? If so, what the stored procedure would be like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, It looks safe.

Because it uses parameters.

You run a risk of SQL-injection when you create queries like
 `baseQueryText + " WHERE Username =" + TextBox.Text;`

Reguarding the Edit: When you use a **Stored Procedure** you always use parameters so they are safe too. No special effort required, but you still could/should filter incoming data.

Comment: +1. It is possible to build stored procedures that are vulnerable, but using parameters like you've said is still safe.
@asmo: You should be able to more-or-less copy your existing code into a stored procedure.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  You are using parameterized queries, which are in general considered safe from SQL injection.

You may still want to consider filtering your inputs anyway.

Comment: You ***do*** want to still filter. After all while a query for `<script>something nasty</script>` is unlikely to find a player, when sent back to the UI (assuming web here) ...

Comment: Right, but that isn't SQL injection but script injection. And the proper way to deal with it is HtmlEncoding in the View. Not that it hurts to restrict a UserName.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all the non-static data is being fed in via bound parameters.